# send mail by bbc not working

Tags: php

hay
i used this code

```
$to       = "mial@live.com,mail@yahoo.com";
$subject  = "Mini-mass Emailer";
$message  = "<a href='#'>Hello World</a>";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Your Name <me@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: {$to}' . "\r\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'ok';
}
```

but see what is happend
every user see the full list of the users

[alt text http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/1289/21811933.gif](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/1289/21811933.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have put all the users in the "to" line. You are also passing them into the "bcc" line too so just doing this may help you but as far as I know you need at least one address in the to line (although this may not be the case). It'll look pretty strange for each person doing it that way though.

The best way to avoid these issues would be to send the email multiple times, once to each user. To modify your code example to do this, I'd do something like the following:

```
$toAddresses = array("mial@live.com", "mail@yahoo.com");
$subject  = "Mini-mass Emailer";
$message  = "<a href='#'>Hello World</a>";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Your Name <me@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";

foreach ($toAddresses as $to) {
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "OK - sent message to {$to}";
    }
}
```

Comment: but i think will cause in inceasing the server load

Comment: Yes it will do, but I am assuming it should not be that much of an issue. If you have to send to a very large number of recipients, splitting them up and running a subset each time might be wise. If it is a relatively small amount, the extra load will be nothing worth worrying about.

Comment: Not too many then. A good way to reduce load on the server is to schedule it for a low-activity point. In addition, rather than firing them all off in the loop you could put in something to introduce a little delay between each one. That'll avoid overwhelming your mail server too quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Your call to mail is passing the $to as the to parameter meaning those emails will be be in the to header try passing an empty string instead. You are passing the info into the bcc header so the email should still get to them that way.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to take this Mail-Class of phpguru.org:
http://www.phpguru.org/static/htmlMimeMail5

There you can specify with setBcc() the addresses which should be "blind", it's pretty easy and works well. I use this class in every project.

Best Regards.